# fopen results in segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen, file-pointer

As in the headline.
Simple exercise, trying to learn structures and other essential c functionality.
Here is a structure containing a char[] and a number, I try to save its values in a file and read them back.
I read through a lot of topics concerning Seg.fault by fopen(), but can't find my mistake!
Someone here who knows why fopen() does crash in this instance?
Any suggestions and criticism on the matter is welcome!

The function where the Segfault happens is `load()`:

```
void load(struct Telephon *structure, int *counter)
{
    char filename[255];
    char puffer[255], puffercpy[255];
    int i, c, newline_count;
    size_t strlaen;
    FILE *datei=NULL;
    char *token=NULL;

    printf("\033[0;35mWelche Datei oeffnen?\033[0m\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    //emptystdin();
    //strlaen=strlen(filename);
    //printf("%d", strlaen);
    //filename[strlaen+1] = '\0';

    //printf("\n%s", filename);

    datei = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(datei==NULL)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mKonnte Datei %s nicht oeffnen.\033[0m\n", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (c=fgetc(datei)) != EOF ) //count lines of file
        {
            if ( c == '\n' )
            {
                newline_count++;
            }

        }

        for(i=0; i<=newline_count; i++) //get values in between ";" 
        {
            fgets(puffer, 254, datei);
            strcpy(puffercpy, puffer);

            token = strtok(puffercpy, ";");
            *counter = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            strcpy(structure[i].name, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            structure[i].nummer = atoi(token);

        }

    fclose(datei);
    }
    return;

}
```

The whole code, main is at the end:

telephonListen.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 100

struct Telephon
{
    char         name[210];
    unsigned int nummer;
}TELE[MAX];

char* gotTime(char *timestrg)
{
    time_t now;
    now = time(NULL);
    strftime (timestrg, 19, "%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M", localtime (&now));
    return timestrg;
}

void printT(struct Telephon *structarray, int addcount)
{   int i;
    if(addcount==0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mEs sind noch keine Eintraege vorhanden!\033[0m\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<addcount; i++)
        {
            printf("\nEintrag Nr.%d\n%s:\t%d\n",i+1, structarray[i].name, structarray[i].nummer);
        }
        return;
    }

}

void eingabe(int num, struct Telephon *structarray)
{
    size_t inputlen;
    int check;
    if(num>MAX)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mMaximale Anzahl von Eintraegen erreicht!\033[0m\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\033[0;35mNamen eingeben:\t\033[0m");
        //fgets(structarray[num].name, MAX, stdin);
        fgets(structarray[num].name, 209, stdin);
        inputlen=strlen(structarray[num].name);
        structarray[num].name[inputlen-1]='\0';
        printf("\n\033[0;35mNummer eingeben:\t \033[0m");
        do
        {
            check = scanf("%10u", &structarray[num].nummer);
        }while( getchar()!='\n');
        fflush(stdin);

        if(check==1)
        {
            printf("Ihr Kontakt wurde angelegt!\n%s:\t%u\n", structarray[num].name ,structarray[num].nummer);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Fehler bei der Eingabe. Kontakt wurde nicht angelegt!");
            return;
        }

        return;
    }

}
void writeFile(struct Telephon *structure, char *zeitf, int counter)
{
    char filename[255];
    int i;
    FILE *datei;

    if(counter>0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;35mIn welche Datei soll das Telephonbuch geschrieben werden?\n(Achtung: Vorhandene Dateien werden ueberschrieben!)\t\033[0m\n");
        scanf("%s", filename);
        getchar();
        datei = fopen(filename, "w");
        if(NULL == datei)
        {
            printf("\033[0;31mKonnte Datei %s nicht öffnen.\033[0m\n", filename);
        }

        fprintf(datei, "Telephonverzeichnis vom %s\nNAME\t\t|NUMMER\n\n", zeitf);
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            fprintf(datei, "%s\t\t|%d\n", structure[i].name, structure[i].nummer);
        }
        printf("\033[0;32mDatei gespeichert.\033[0m\n");
        fclose(datei);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mEs sind noch keine Eintraege vorhanden!\033[0m\n");
        return;
    }
    return;

}

void change(struct Telephon *structure, int count)
{
    int eintragnum;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mEs sind noch keine Eintraege vorhanden!\033[0m\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printT(structure, count);
        printf("\033[0;31mWelcher Eintrag soll geaendert werden?\033[0m\n");
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &eintragnum);
        }while(getchar()!='\n');

        if(eintragnum<1||eintragnum>count)
        {
            printf("\033[0;31mBitte die Nummer [zwischen %d und %d]\n des zu aendernden Eintrags eingeben!\033[0m\n", 1, count);
        }
        else
        {
            eingabe(eintragnum-1, structure);
        }

    }

    return;
}
void emptystdin()
{
  int c;
  while( ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n') );
}
void searchContact(struct Telephon *structure, int count)
{
    char searchC;
    int inputlen;
    int i=0;
    int countcompare;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mEs sind noch keine Eintraege vorhanden!\033[0m\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Anfangsbuchstabe:\t");
        scanf("%c", &searchC);
        emptystdin();

        for(i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                if(structure[i].name[0]==searchC)
                {
                    printf("Eintrag gefunden:\n");
                    printf("Nr. %d\nName:\t%s\nNummer:\t%u\n", i+1, structure[i].name, structure[i].nummer);
                }

            }
        return;
    }

}


void save(struct Telephon *structure, int counter)
{
    char filename[255];
    int i;
    FILE *datei;

    if(counter>0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;35mUnter welchem Dateinamen speichern?\n(Achtung: Vorhandene Dateien werden ueberschrieben!)\t\033[0m\n");
        scanf("%s", filename);
        emptystdin();
        datei = fopen(filename, "w");
        if(NULL == datei)
        {
            printf("\033[0;31mKonnte Datei %s nicht anlegen.\033[0m\n", filename);
        }

        for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            fprintf(datei, "%d;%s;%d\n", i+1, structure[i].name, structure[i].nummer);
        }
        printf("\033[0;32mDatei gespeichert.\033[0m\n");
        fclose(datei);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mEs sind noch keine Eintraege vorhanden!\033[0m\n");
    }
    return;
}




void load(struct Telephon *structure, int *counter)
{
    char filename[255];
    char puffer[255], puffercpy[255];
    int i, c, newline_count;
    size_t strlaen;
    FILE *datei=NULL;
    char *token=NULL;

    printf("\033[0;35mWelche Datei oeffnen?\033[0m\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    //emptystdin();
    //strlaen=strlen(filename);
    //printf("%d", strlaen);
    //filename[strlaen+1] = '\0';

    //printf("\n%s", filename);

    datei = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(datei==NULL)
    {
        printf("\033[0;31mKonnte Datei %s nicht oeffnen.\033[0m\n", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (c=fgetc(datei)) != EOF ) //Zeilen in Datei zählen
        {
            if ( c == '\n' )
            {
                newline_count++;
            }

        }

        for(i=0; i<=newline_count; i++) //CVS parsen/auslesen
        {
            fgets(puffer, 254, datei);
            strcpy(puffercpy, puffer);

            token = strtok(puffercpy, ";");
            *counter = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            strcpy(structure[i].name, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            structure[i].nummer = atoi(token);

        }

    fclose(datei);
    }
    return;

}

int main(void)
{
    int auswahl;
    int count = 0;
    char zeit[20];
    char buffer[2];
    struct Telephon *structptr; //malloc(MAX*(sizeof(TELE)));
    structptr = TELE;

    gotTime(zeit);
    system("clear");
    printf("Telephonkontaktverwaltung\t%s\n", zeit);


    do
    {

        printf("\033[30;47m1: Kontakt hinzufuegen\t2: Kontakte anzeigen\n3: Kontakt aendern\t4: Als Datei speichern\n5. Kontakt suchen\n6. Als CVS sichern\t7. Aus CVS laden\n8. Beenden\nEine der Ziffern eingeben, mit Enter bestaetigen\033[0m\n");

        /*
        scanf("%d", &auswahl);
        scanf("%c", &buffer);

        fgets(buffer, 2, stdin);
        if(isdigit(buffer[1]))
        {
            auswahl=atoi(buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Eine der Nummern eingeben um Aktion auszufuehren!\n");
        }


        do
        {
           scanf("%d", &auswahl);
        }while(getchar()!='\n');

        fgets(buffer, 2, stdin);
        sscanf(buffer, "%d", &auswahl);
        */

        scanf("%d", &auswahl);
        emptystdin();




        switch (auswahl)
        {
            case 1  :   eingabe(count++, structptr);
                        break;
            case 2  :   printT(structptr, count);
                        break;
            case 3  :   change(structptr, count);
                        break;
            case 4  :   writeFile(structptr, gotTime(zeit), count);
                        break;
            case 5  :   searchContact(structptr, count);
                        break;
            case 6  :   save(structptr, count);
                        break;
            case 7  :   load(structptr, &count);
                        break;
            case 8  :   printf("ENDE\n");
                        break;
            default :   printf("Eine der Nummern eingeben um Aktion auszufuehren!\n");
                        break;
        }



    }while(auswahl!=8);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Better to ask on Code review.

Comment: I was told should only ask about working code there, and about malfunctioning code here

Comment: The one in `load(. . .)`

Comment: So you start the program, enter `7`, enter the file name and the program crashes at `fopen()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. fopen() works in the other functions

Comment: From what do you conclude it's `fopen()` that crashes? It might very well, that the code after `fopen()` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rewind()`.

Between the `while()` and `for()` loops, the file need to start at the beginning again.

```
while ( (c=fgetc(datei)) != EOF ) //count lines of file
  { ...}
rewind(datei);
for(i=0; i<=newline_count; i++) //get values in between ";"
   { ...}
```

---

*Strongly* suggest avoid using `scanf()` and `fgets(,,stdin)`.  Recommend one.  Preferable `fgets()`.

You likely want `scanf(" %c",` instead of `scanf("%c",`.  (Add space).

---

Minor Idea:
Not that English is the be-all end-all language, but OP may want to consider something like

```
// Bold Red "Could not create file" EOL
const char *Err_FileCreation_format = "\033[0;31mKonnte Datei %s nicht anlegen.\033[0m\n"
printf(Err_FileCreation_format, filename);
// or 
#define Err_FileCreation_fmt1 "\033[0;31mKonnte Datei "
#define Err_FileCreation_fmt2 " nicht anlegen.\033[0m\n"
printf(Err_FileCreation_fmt1 "%s" Err_FileCreation_fmt2, filename);
```

Comment: It was the call to `rewind()` now everything is working, thanks a lot for the recommendations! And the minor Idea especially! It was a pain in the eyes before.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Consider up voting the answers that proved useful.

Comment: Actually the error text in non-English is minor (and there is no reason to split it), but I **would** recommend not embedding escape sequences directly. Either using curses/ [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) for POSIX systems, or at least using `#define ANSI_Bold_Red "\033[0;31m"` and `#define ANSI_Off "\033[0m"` and using the compiler's string concatenation, e.g. `printf(ANSI_Bold_Red "Konnte Datei %s nicht anlegen." ANSI_Off "\n", filename);` Note there are **no** commas better the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming undefined behaviour hadn't been invoked prior to a call to `fopen()` the only way to make it crash is to pass it a non-initialised or non-`0`-terminated character array as file name or mode.

So to avoid this properly initialise all variables used to hold a file name and/or mode by declaring it like:

```
char filename[256] = "";
```

To avoid allowing `scanf()` to read in more then `filename`can hold do like this:

```
scanf("%255s", filename);
```

---

**Update**:

This code

```
        while ( (c=fgetc(datei)) != EOF ) //count lines of file
        {
            if ( c == '\n' )
            {
                newline_count++;
            }

        }
```

reads until the end of the file.

So this code

```
        for(i=0; i<=newline_count; i++) //get values in between ";" 
        {
            fgets(puffer, 254, datei);
            strcpy(puffercpy, puffer);

            token = strtok(puffercpy, ";");
            *counter = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            strcpy(structure[i].name, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            structure[i].nummer = atoi(token);

        }
```

would not be able to read anything, as eof had already been reached.

However the code does not test whether `fgets()` might have failed but happily starts parsing what it didn't read and ... crashes during `atoi()`ing a token pointing to `NULL`.

Comment: I tried with initialising the file-pointer with NULL; the segfault happens even when I pass the name of an existing filename directly. Wrong filename sets filepointer to NULL, program works fine. But correct filename results in segfault. Tried the above mentioned initialisation with "", too.

Comment: @rrrrn: You did `#include <stdio.h>`, didn't you?

Comment: yes, stdio.h is included. I get the following output after the segmentation fault msg: process returned 139 (0x8B)